# Cannot reshape array of size 470 into shape (20)

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, pickle

Before stating the problem, Let me clear that I am a newbie to Python and Pycharm. 
Actually i am running a code from GitHub on Pycharm having python 3.7.1 installed. I am unable to understand the error.

There are many related questions regarding to this error but i am not getting the required solution. People have different parameters. they have some kind of integers in the array reshaping parenthesis. I am also not getting what is "reshape_size".

```
    for fname in filelist_in_order:
        f = open(fname, 'rb')
        complete_array_part = pickle.load(f)
        complete_array_part = complete_array_part.reshape(-1, reshape_size)
        if (first_access):
            complete_array = complete_array_part
            first_access = False
        else:
            complete_array = np.concatenate((complete_array, complete_array_part), axis=0)
    return complete_array
```

Error Message is:

```
complete_array_part = complete_array_part.reshape(-1, reshape_size)
```

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 470 into shape (20)

So the output when i checked the Complete_Array_Part was:

[ 0.17789184  0.30629522  0.27276194  0.17626782 -0.37863299 -0.25997388
 -0.06388663 -0.12540221 -0.14847486 -0.34351087  0.09123761  0.29326397
  0.28769037  0.18113655 -0.282704   -0.32993543 -0.09362718 -0.0762426
 -0.13316527 -0.31239721  0.0888922   0.42159474  0.26748142  0.21263877
 -0.35531974 -0.25320625  0.01957267 -0.08911581  0.02139289 -0.35609692
 -0.02162258  0.27158457  0.24833584  0.22414273 -0.25294834 -0.25598195
 -0.00261908 -0.16378632 -0.16722032 -0.28330618  0.11813667  0.4059473
  0.20328876  0.19888923 -0.17746535 -0.24519044 -0.06206651 -0.1454512
 -0.147276   -0.25637549  0.01985414  0.2562502   0.25700885  0.22300856
 -0.26829335 -0.3002809  -0.05610409 -0.14334358 -0.13960308 -0.25650957
  0.04738852  0.30026013  0.17591953  0.214241   -0.19861142 -0.33769739
  0.00736059 -0.07837114 -0.19286683 -0.25786099  0.09123761  0.29326397
  0.28769037  0.18113655 -0.282704   -0.32993543 -0.09362718 -0.0762426
 -0.13316527 -0.31239721  0.1030243   0.30424696  0.22326529  0.17811422
 -0.22068222 -0.27857596  0.00819118 -0.1030729  -0.10017776 -0.19125859
  0.10184187  0.34402201  0.16981423  0.22493245 -0.26154083 -0.35094687
 -0.11193486 -0.10435168 -0.11710036 -0.2646451   0.18112525  0.16479042
  0.20678186  0.208013   -0.33933938 -0.39654118  0.10261163 -0.05978006
 -0.09965867 -0.24144523 -0.03096133  0.25541702  0.264617    0.18827559
 -0.27278233 -0.27280146 -0.01961248  0.04128763 -0.16926275 -0.25017616
  0.1685964   0.2472322   0.16320953  0.11125059 -0.33302104 -0.32924467
  0.06027375  0.01118627 -0.12375752 -0.36029184  0.05984636  0.40982607
  0.29108658  0.24611495 -0.32725531 -0.29316714 -0.00595155 -0.16829109
 -0.01524433 -0.31738156  0.14332619  0.37219125  0.35616517  0.07771102
 -0.41376531 -0.29962835 -0.08480088 -0.12293065  0.04588581 -0.37282506
  0.26338899  0.18212023  0.30509233  0.03429261 -0.46090066 -0.62543684
  0.14560741 -0.23207924 -0.10377936 -0.34899354  0.10678266  0.31017959
  0.29039884  0.18984702 -0.30641529 -0.37125492  0.00190322 -0.090801
  0.00383001 -0.31131977  0.11976989  0.24804372  0.1798858   0.20221336
 -0.2672568  -0.27686304  0.09393801 -0.08291434 -0.15147643 -0.26258913
  0.07006255  0.24292895  0.2479758   0.12545972 -0.28571904 -0.2246163
  0.02192843 -0.09310064 -0.19140819 -0.3822245   0.15050775  0.24107212
  0.31406438  0.07037568 -0.28054947 -0.30401161 -0.07911987  0.02704167
 -0.03337537 -0.35185724  0.08345325  0.45238137  0.24365583  0.13630277
 -0.26385203 -0.27017274 -0.0053592  -0.16803598 -0.13584027 -0.29801774
  0.06169732  0.28122491  0.20148738  0.12553374 -0.32540709 -0.24335477
 -0.03755248 -0.00100566 -0.0509242  -0.33147877  0.07427905  0.18317398
  0.35396093  0.18327162 -0.31448454 -0.38967571 -0.02551728 -0.23432273
 -0.16113353 -0.28115082  0.06879958  0.22342694  0.17293574  0.14878762
 -0.34089816 -0.35571763 -0.11643556 -0.09598652 -0.00672829 -0.27351999
  0.06069776  0.17189354  0.22681117  0.16899896 -0.32868099 -0.37247849
 -0.1136125  -0.15183234 -0.17877081 -0.35204101  0.24152195  0.24887547
  0.32604483  0.25527418 -0.35900906 -0.40607622 -0.04806738 -0.20694411
 -0.05488034 -0.26493907  0.17528442  0.30049577  0.1629622   0.20871069
 -0.22320881 -0.36587471  0.20252028 -0.14161371 -0.1282679  -0.24894838
  0.0888922   0.42159474  0.26748142  0.21263877 -0.35531974 -0.25320625
  0.01957267 -0.08911581  0.02139289 -0.35609692  0.12388916  0.33917072
  0.42795435  0.08663616 -0.3915118  -0.43263063 -0.01308431 -0.09523527
 -0.08210509 -0.39892739  0.1860335   0.22147226  0.23963733  0.12970485
 -0.32032195 -0.36106503  0.02424989 -0.07740933 -0.10642112 -0.30477303
  0.12551595  0.30433181  0.35763353  0.28385532 -0.43477935 -0.34082446
 -0.02719706 -0.44719821  0.27575466 -0.28147447  0.23355711  0.32526308
  0.41331318  0.2257646  -0.40978959 -0.45557061  0.04251576 -0.07252584
 -0.12531641 -0.31281373  0.18305443  0.1704032   0.24024118  0.16669753
 -0.27432877 -0.38038296  0.09402332 -0.06208001 -0.18470117 -0.2516017
  0.06363131  0.20514129  0.22846916  0.08167504 -0.25951183 -0.32592475
  0.01168576 -0.12991063 -0.10443141 -0.26863056  0.25425208  0.31902471
  0.33302572  0.22676007 -0.33653393 -0.38779891 -0.01722381 -0.1111242
 -0.22871622 -0.3331289   0.11495201  0.41839725  0.19331557  0.20344175
 -0.2456654  -0.20443794  0.00504544 -0.2100333  -0.08358113 -0.33943006
  0.26854891  0.30015546  0.31847724  0.18569888 -0.31109962 -0.41813236
  0.03507741 -0.02907968 -0.20126076 -0.32520163  0.07898337  0.33653653
  0.34216624  0.24134663 -0.29218262 -0.32460195 -0.08944514 -0.09410556
 -0.01705393 -0.40615028  0.10629132  0.2604306   0.2255978   0.04821964
 -0.26977044 -0.38201541 -0.06466427 -0.19278997 -0.09640036 -0.21310115
  0.01773387  0.22970651  0.31858417  0.21676925 -0.23561591 -0.41310543
  0.12385868 -0.14431895 -0.1570266  -0.29954869  0.0915345   0.25607604
  0.23845172  0.21028796 -0.32377386 -0.33092183 -0.00443996 -0.24734242
 -0.17844367 -0.2985107   0.14641258  0.33784047  0.17312077  0.20297053
 -0.17508766 -0.2666209   0.1487464  -0.08262923 -0.07993621 -0.3536256
  0.27124339  0.17663571  0.29459208  0.14568396 -0.35805491 -0.45823082
  0.02555789 -0.20574869 -0.1970185  -0.21216772 -0.02660971  0.18790659
  0.28153318  0.18746425 -0.24937677 -0.30586433 -0.07034364 -0.05794065
 -0.06758652 -0.33423638  0.2193345   0.31134152  0.33954287  0.16869812
 -0.3541418  -0.35929483 -0.01552734 -0.01932855 -0.07188252 -0.34194604
  0.09554033  0.31854007  0.3243461   0.15001382 -0.32146809 -0.29419503
 -0.10843883 -0.11347267 -0.11110444 -0.34457517  0.22696011  0.20718208
  0.37935093  0.06550272 -0.27321219 -0.38913769 -0.123006    0.01007091
  0.09978335 -0.32427335]

complete array part shape    (470,)

complete array part size    470

reshape size    20

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to unpack here, and we can't solve everything in one answer.

But maybe this helps.

`reshape`changes the dimensions of the array. For example, an array with 6 elements could be consisting of one column of 6 elements, 2 columns of 3 elements , 3 columns of 2 elements, 1 row of 6 elements.

You should try this out in a python console to familiarize yourself with reshape:

```py
import numpy as np #this loads the module numpy and assigns the name "np" to it

a=np.zeros(6) # create an array filled with 0s of 6 elements

print(a) # shows contents to the screen
# this outputs [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

print(a.reshape((2,3)))
# this outputs
# [[ 0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

print(a.reshape((3,2)))
# this outputs
# [[ 0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.]]
```

As you can see, the `reshape` function changed the dimensions of the array, but not its values. Also you should note, that I could not have reshaped it to, say, a 2x4 array, as this array would have a different number of elements then the starting one.

After you understand this, try to see why your program is failing...

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I have studied Array reshaping in detail. but i still cannot find the solution to the problem.

I am editing the question details. Please let me know if you can help me out in this..?

Comment: @RababHafeez well, you have an array with 470 elements, and you are asking to reshape it as an array of 20 elements - this is not possible, because reshape is not meant to change the content and number of elements of the array.

Comment: Please clarify...
I am doing it as:
complete_array_part.reshape(-1, reshape_size)
where reshape_size is 20
so it becomes:
complete_array_part.reshape(-1, 20)

what i understand is I am not changing content .... by this "-1" there are unknown number of rows but the columns would be 20???

Comment: @RababHafeez if you were to do reshape(-1,470) then the effect would be to transpose the array 470X1 into a 1x470. This would be allowed and should work. But you cannot reshape(-1,20) - this will never work. There is nothing more to say about that, you will have to figure out why there is a 20 vs 470 mismatch there. You may be trying to read the wrong data, or there may be a bug somewhere in the program, or many other possibilities. We cannot help you with that, as we have no idea what's going on behind the curtains.